# What does Geryon have to do with singing?

Tags: etymology, greek, mythology

One of the Labors of Heracles involved a three-headed giant named Geryon (Γηρυών). I've never seen an explanation for this name, but at first glance it would seem to be connected to γηρύω "to sing" (participle γηρυών "singing").

Is there any connection between the mythological giant and singing? Otherwise, where did the name come from, if not from γηρύω?

Comment: Far from a conclusive answer, but "singing" is a peculiar development, confined to Greek. Other IE languages developed a kindred word with the meaning centering on a loud, harsh cry of a bird or animal (Balt., Slav., Germ.), or a crackling sound (Skt. járati, of fire). And Γη- is also not a impossibility.